# Django - retrieve api url from template and pass to views

Tags: python, django, api, templates

I am using Cryptocompare.com api to load news from cryptocurrencies world. In the template I am looping through it show it on the home-page. I would like to add feature that if  you click send button it will send an email to you with the link for the news you just clicked. What is the best way to do it? I tried that, but I dont know how to link the clicked element with the url in views.

```
def home(request):
    # Grab Crypto News
    api_request = requests.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN')
    api = json.loads(api_request.content)
    return render(request, 'crypto/crypto_home.html', {'api': api})

def SendLink(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = 'Link to crypto news'
        from_email = 'test@gmail.com' 
        message = 'Hello {}, here is your link:'.format(request.user) 
        to_email = [request.user.email]

        send_mail(
          subject,
          message,
          from_email,
          to_email
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('crypto-home'))
```

Template:

```
    {% for x in api.Data %}
        <div class='col-sm'>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ x.imageurl }}" alt="{{ x.source }}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{x.title}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ x.body|safe }}.</p>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role='group'>
                        <a href="{{x.url}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'send_link' %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button id="{{x.id}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Send to e-mail</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I would like to add link from template 'x.url' to views to be able to add the link to the message variable. I also tried to link it via ID of the news but I am not able to pass it to the views. Any idea how I can do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add a hidden field to your form for the URL you'd like to pass to your view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="URL" name="URL" value="{{x.url}}">
```

Once you have that variable in your view you should be able to add it to your email template.

Comment: And how I can access the 'value' in the views?

Comment: I can access it in views with: request.POST['URL']